# Error Loading XML File {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}

Tags: c#, xml

I have searched a few topics on this error but none of them seem to be giving me a resolution.

I have trying to use xml source data to create an instance of my class using code first mvc c#.

My Model looks like this:

```
namespace PSA.Models
{
public class PunchRoundRule:IPunchRoundRule
{
    public virtual int PunchRoundRuleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="In Punch Early Inside Round")]
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyInsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unscheduled Out Round")]
    public virtual string UnscheduledOutRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Early Outside Grace")]
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Early Outside Round")]
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyOutsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Early Change Point")]
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyChangePoint { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Early Inside Grace")]
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Late Outside Round")]
    public virtual string OutPunchLateOutsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Late Inside Round")]
    public virtual string OutPunchLateInsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Late Change Point")]
    public virtual string InPunchLateChangePoint { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Transfer Round")]
    public virtual string TransferRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unscheduled Out Grace")]
    public virtual string UnscheduledOutGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Transfer Grace")]
    public virtual string TransferGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Is Missed Out Exception")]
    public virtual bool IsMissedOutException { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Late Inside Grace")]
    public virtual string OutPunchLateInsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Late Outside Round")]
    public virtual string InPunchLateOutsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Late Outside Grace")]
    public virtual string InPunchLateOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Early Change Point")]
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyChangePoint { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unscheduled In Round")]
    public virtual string UnscheduledInRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Early Inside Grace")]
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyInsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Late Outside Grace")]
    public virtual string OutPunchLateOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Late Inside Round")]
    public virtual string InPunchLateInsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Punch Late Inside Grace")]
    public virtual string InPunchLateInsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Use Scheduled Out")]
    public virtual bool UseScheduledOut { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Early Outside Round")]
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Early Outside Grace")]
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Early Inside Round")]
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyInsideRound { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unscheduled In Grace")]
    public virtual string UnscheduledInGrace { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Out Punch Late Change Point")]
    public virtual string OutPunchLateChangePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual int WorkRuleId { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkRule WorkRule { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<PunchRoundRule> punchRoundRule = GetPunchRoundRule<PunchRoundRule>("http://localhost:12276/Files/WSAPunchRoundRule.xml");

    static IEnumerable<T> GetPunchRoundRule<T>(String xml)
    where T : IPunchRoundRule, new()
    {
        return XElement.Parse(xml)
            .Elements("Response")
            .Select(f => new T
            {
                PunchRoundRuleId=10,
                Name = f.Element("name").Value,

            });
    }

    public PunchRoundRule()
    {
        this.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
    }

}
public interface IPunchRoundRule
{
    int PunchRoundRuleId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}


}
```

My Xml File looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response Status="Success" action="RetrieveAllForUpdate">
  <WSAPunchRoundRule InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" UseScheduledOut="false" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" Name="Default Early Start" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00"/>
  <WSAPunchRoundRule InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" UseScheduledOut="false" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" Name="Ramadan" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00"/>
  <WSAPunchRoundRule InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="false" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" UseScheduledOut="true" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" Name="Transfer Rounding" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00"/>
  <WSAPunchRoundRule InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" UseScheduledOut="false" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" Name="Workrule Rounding" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: `name` is an `Attribute`, not an `Element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error implies that you have a not-well formed XML document. Are you sure that the provided XML is the one you are actually referencing in your code? While it seems OK to me, I would suggest trying to open it with another XML editor or a web browser to confirm that it is OK.

Another reason for getting this exception could be if you have a wrong path and the stream returns `null`. Or you could have no rights to access the specific file and therefore get `null` out of the stream. Try to read the file without parsing it just to check it out.

Hope I helped!